# RDD.union vs SparkContex.union

Tags: apache-spark

What is the difference between

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y), myRDDlist)
```

which calls [RDD.union](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) and

```
sc.union(myRDDlist)
```

which calls [SparkContext.union](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext)?

Do they compile to the same code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[SparkContext.union](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Forg%2Fapache%2Fspark%2FSparkContext.scala#L975) and [RDD.union](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L471) are equivalent, if you have two RDDs.

Reducing over a list of RDDs and calling RDD.union will result in several nested UnionRDDs (referencing each other), where the call to SparkContext.union will result in only a single UnionRDD.