# Merge Multiple JavaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've attempted to merge multiple JavaRDD but i get only 2 merged can someone kindly help. I've been struggling with this for a while but overall i would like to be able to obtain multiple collections and use sqlContext create a group and print out all results.

here my code

```
  JavaRDD<AppLog> logs =  mapCollection(sc, "mongodb://hadoopUser:Pocup1ne9@localhost:27017/hbdata.ppa_logs").union(
                              mapCollection(sc, "mongodb://hadoopUser:Pocup1ne9@localhost:27017/hbdata.fav_logs").union(
                                mapCollection(sc, "mongodb://hadoopUser:Pocup1ne9@localhost:27017/hbdata.pps_logs").union(
                                  mapCollection(sc, "mongodb://hadoopUser:Pocup1ne9@localhost:27017/hbdata.dd_logs").union(
                                    mapCollection(sc, "mongodb://hadoopUser:Pocup1ne9@localhost:27017/hbdata.ppt_logs")
                                  )
                                )
                              )
                          );


public JavaRDD<AppLog> mapCollection(JavaSparkContext sc ,String uri){

  Configuration mongodbConfig = new Configuration();
  mongodbConfig.set("mongo.job.input.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat");
  mongodbConfig.set("mongo.input.uri", uri);

  JavaPairRDD<Object, BSONObject> documents = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
      mongodbConfig,            // Configuration
      MongoInputFormat.class,   // InputFormat: read from a live cluster.
      Object.class,             // Key class
      BSONObject.class          // Value class
    );

    return documents.map(

      new Function<Tuple2<Object, BSONObject>, AppLog>() {

          public AppLog call(final Tuple2<Object, BSONObject> tuple) {
              AppLog log = new AppLog();
              BSONObject header =
                (BSONObject) tuple._2();

              log.setTarget((String) header.get("target"));
              log.setAction((String) header.get("action"));

              return log;
          }
      }
    );
}
```

// printing the collections
        SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);

```
    DataFrame logsSchema = sqlContext.createDataFrame(logs, AppLog.class);
    logsSchema.registerTempTable("logs");

    DataFrame groupedMessages = sqlContext.sql(
      "select * from logs");
      // "select target, action, Count(*) from logs group by target, action");

      // "SELECT to, body FROM messages WHERE to = \"eric.bass@enron.com\"");



    groupedMessages.show();

    logsSchema.printSchema();
```

Comment: how do you recognize that just two RDDs are united?

second question: why do you call the union in recursive way (i know it isnt executed recursively) and not in functional writing style? I mean rdd1.union(rdd2).union(rdd3) and so and. the return type of an union should be an rdd. in your writing style -> mapCollection(sth1, sth2).union(mapCollection(sth1,sth2)) and so on

Comment: Hi, i used the sqlcontext to print the rdd and it only show two rdd after running my code. I've updated my question above so you can see how ive printed the data. i used the recursive style code as ive tried many ways but it hasnt worked this is the closest ive came. any recommendation?

Comment: It seems correct for me. The only thing which confuses me is the recursive writing style. Perhaps you could load each log rdd and do the join later and print the count or the first elements of each rdd to see if they are not empty. The functional writing style will lead for better readability its just a recommendation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to merge multiple `JavaRDDs` , simply use `sc.union(rdd1,rdd2,..)` instead `rdd1.union(rdd2).union(rdd3)`.

Also check this [RDD.union vs SparkContex.union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173160/rdd-union-vs-sparkcontex-union)

Comment: thanks for the help. it seems like i still only get the first two rdd joined not too sure why

Comment: Someone please slap me. I noticed at the bottom of where i print out my values it says "only showing top 20 rows". I've been working on this for the past 6-7 hours