# Combining RDD's in a loop

Tags: apache-spark

Here is my scenario :

I have a list of RDD called fileNamesList .

```
List<JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>>> fileNamesList = new ArrayList<JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>>>();

fileNamesList.add(newRDD); //adding RDD's to list
```

I am adding multiple newRDD's into the list, this is inside a loop.So the list grows up to 10 maximum .

I want to combine(union) all the RDD's inside the list `fileNamesList`  . Is it possible to do like below ;

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> finalFileNames ;

    for (int j = 0; j < IdList.size()-1; j++) {


        finalFileNames = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(fileNamesList.get(j)).
                union(JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(fileNamesList.get(j + 1)));
    }
```

Or what is the other option that I could use .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SparkContext.union or JavaSparkContext.union. It can union many RDD, in result you have much simpler DAG. See [RDD.union vs SparkContex.union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173160/rdd-union-vs-sparkcontex-union)